# Local provider hosted add-in reachable to SharePoint on-premise?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I have tried searching in Microsoft Documentation and on forums, but cant seem to find any information about it.

Is it possible to localhost a web-service, that isn't reachable from outside the local network, and add it to a SharePoint on-premise server hosted on the same network?

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. Can you deploy a provider hosted app to the same server as SharePoint? Yes. Can you configure it so the provider hosted app is not available to the outside world? Yes. Can external users who access the sharepoint box also run the provider hosted app? No.